# How can I start the audio file without clicking?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, howler.js

I use howler.js to play MP3. But this audio file does not start without clicking anywhere.

Here is the Google console warning;

```
howler.min.js:2 The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page.
```

JS codes I made;

```
var sound = new Howl({
    src: ['havaifisek.mp3']
});

// Clear listener after first call.
sound.once('load', function() {
    sound.play();
});

// Fires when the sound finishes playing.
sound.on('end', function() {
    $('#app').css('opacity', 1);
    $('#canvas').css('display', 'none');
});
```

Comment: Okay, I fixed. chrome://settings/content/sound added my site.